# \iftrue in \let "swallowing" the following \fi

Tags: errors, tex-core

I already searched for comparable questions, but found none with this problem.

I have the following LaTeX formatting section to define inline and multiline comments that can be "in-commented" at one stroke by replacing `iffalse` with `iftrue`:

```
\providecommand{\comment}[1]{}
\let\commentstart=\iffalse
\let\commentend=\fi
\iffalse
\renewcommand{\comment}[1]{#1}
%\let\commentstart=\iftrue
\fi
```

However, I had to outcomment the line that sets `commentstart` to `iftrue` because otherwise it produces the following error:

```
pdflatex.exe> ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 12.
pdflatex.exe> <inserted text> 
pdflatex.exe>                 \fi 
pdflatex.exe> <*> document.tex
pdflatex.exe>                 
pdflatex.exe> ! Emergency stop.
pdflatex.exe> <*> document.tex
pdflatex.exe>                 
pdflatex.exe> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
pdflatex.exe> Transcript written on document.log.
```

From this error I assume that the line claims the next `\fi` for itself. However, I thought `\let` should suppress that? Or is the `\iftrue` processed earlier than the `\let`? Are there any ways to establish the expected behavior?

Here is the full Texlipse console output:

```
running: C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials document.tex 
pdflatex.exe> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
pdflatex.exe>  restricted \write18 enabled.
pdflatex.exe>  Source specials enabled.
pdflatex.exe> entering extended mode
pdflatex.exe> (./document.tex
pdflatex.exe> LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
pdflatex.exe> Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrreprt.cls
pdflatex.exe> Document Class: scrreprt 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class (report)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
pdflatex.exe> Package scrlfile, 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
pdflatex.exe>                   Copyright (C) Markus Kohm
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> ))) (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
pdflatex.exe> Package typearea, 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (type area)
pdflatex.exe>                   Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
pdflatex.exe>                   Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> )) (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def))))
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
pdflatex.exe> (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)))
pdflatex.exe> ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 12.
pdflatex.exe> <inserted text> 
pdflatex.exe>                 \fi 
pdflatex.exe> <*> document.tex
pdflatex.exe>                 
pdflatex.exe> ! Emergency stop.
pdflatex.exe> <*> document.tex
pdflatex.exe>                 
pdflatex.exe> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
pdflatex.exe> Transcript written on document.log.
```

Comment: Since it's `\iffalse` what's inside is not processed at all; however, conditionals in TeX, keep track of `\if..\fi` pairs inside of them (which lets you do `\iffalse \ifnum1=1 foo\fi \fi` with no problem). But only conditionals, TeX is not aware of the rest of tokens, so `\let\commentstart=\iftrue` is exactly the same as `\foo\bar!\iftrue` (the only one that actually understands is the `\iftrue`) hence it doesn't have any way of *knowing*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditionals keep track only of certain tokens (als conditionals) which lets you have many of them inside others (my English is not fluent today). Easy solution: add `\fi` in any way you can to balance the `\if..\fi`s.

```
\providecommand*\comment[1]{}
\let\commentstart=\iffalse
\let\commentend=\fi
\iffalse
\renewcommand\comment[1]{#1}
\let\commentstart=\iftrue
\let\commentend=\fi
\fi
```

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks. That's typical of performance-focused processing. Personally I'd like it better if LaTeX first processed it, then threw away everything that's no actual conditional. That would cause less bugs.

Comment: The skipping process using conditionals scans not only real `\fi`, `\if` etc. but the control sequences with the *meaning* of these primitives too. So your example between `\iffalse` and `\fi` says: `\iffalse \r \c [1]{#1}\l\iffalse=\iftrue \l\fi=\fi \fi`

Comment: @EgorHans It isn't about performance: often it isn't possible to process the code in the non-taken branch, for example it might contain undefined commands.

Comment: @wipet Oh, completely true. It just works in this case because they are exactly paired.

Comment: @Gilles Completely right, haven't thought of that it may depend on other `\iffalse`, or similar.

Comment: @EgorHans If you want a more LaTeX-approach to conditionals, take a look at booleans and toggles in `etoolbox` package. And for this specific problem, there are a few packages, for instance `comment` package.

Comment: @wipet Yeah, I expected that once it was clear to me that false branches are actually preventively skipped. But on a true branch, that will still overwrite the custom definition, not the default `\iffalse`, right?

Comment: @Manuel The problem about `comment` package is, it's not defined (from what I understood) what happens if there is a disabled comment command in the code. Actually I would expect the code to crash, as the disabled comment is no longer a defined command (or environment).

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple: when TeX skips over tokens in the “false branch” of a conditional, it still keeps track of conditionals. So the `\iftrue` in the “false branch” needs a matching `\fi`, which TeX finds in the one you wanted to match the initial `\iffalse`. So the false branch is not yet finished and TeX basically gobbles everything until finding `\else` or `\fi`.

The most common trick is to hide the conditional in a macro.

```
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{} % not \providecommand
\let\commentstart=\iffalse
\let\commentend=\fi
\newcommand{\setcommentstarttrue}{\let\commentstart\iftrue}
\iffalse
\renewcommand{\comment}[1]{#1}
\setcommentstarttrue
\fi
```

But you probably want to do this in a different way.

```
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
\makeatletter
\let\commentend=\fi
\newcommand{\showcomments}{%
  \let\commentstart\iftrue
  \let\comment\@firstofone
}
\newcommand{\hidecomments}{%
  \let\commentstart\iffalse
  \let\comment\@gobble
}
\makeatother
\hidecomments % can be \showcomments
```

Comment: thanks but I like Manuel's solution better (still upvoted though)